# how to transform XML files before processing xinclude

Tags: xml, xinclude, xslt

I have numerous XML files that are organized into different directories.  I need to combine them and transform the result using XSLT.  So far, I have already done this except for one problem: some XML files need to be transformed first before it can be included into the result.  xinclude seems to ignore the xml-stylesheet declaration.

How can i transform XML files before they are xincluded?

Regards,

[ simon.cpu ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is the process run? With a `Makefile` or something like that? In that case, add explicit calls to xsltproc before the inclusion and then xinclude the output of xsltproc.

If xsltproc can read the processing instruction (`xml-stylesheet`, note that I did not test that), you do not even have to indicate explicitely the stylesheet to use.

Comment: I think I'll either write a Bourne shell or PHP script.  Someone at IRC gave the same suggestion too: do a two-pass operation and xinclude the result.

I wish xinclude supported XSLT... =)

Answer (score 1):

Break it up into multiple transform calls, first prepare the xml files, then do your main transformation.